# One-liner loop using only recursion in scala

Tags: scala

I'm not sure where to ask this... (it doesn't quite fit the code-golf stackoverflow community)

I have this proof-of-concept javascript snippet that loops without for/while loops by using recursion:

```
(x=>x(x))(x=>{console.log('...'); x(x);})
```

Is there an equivalent ***one-liner*** scala snippet that would do the same? (again, using *only* recursion to achieve looping)?

Comment: Using recursion is very popular in Scala. Just search into it's main library for @tailrec, which is an optimization for tail recursion and you will find your inspiration.

Comment: Yes, but will it be a *one-liner*?

Comment: Your method contains two statements so is arguably not a one liner

Comment: By one-liner I mean no newlines when using a text editor

Comment: Basically, yes, everything can be one liner, it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: "By one-liner I mean no newlines when using a text editor" – That is a completely useless criterium. In many languages, you can remove *all* newlines, and thus make an arbitrarily complex program always be a one-liner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can do this:

```
def loop(): Unit = { println("loop"); loop() }
```

Or this:

```
def loop[A](f: (A => A) = (loop[A] _)): A = { println("loop"); loop(f) }
```

But I do not see what is the value, it is just a dumb infinite function.

Comment: Got this error:  missing argument list for method identity in object Predef
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `identity _` or `identity(_)` instead of `identity`.

Comment: @RuHasha yeah I tried to make it more complex than it needed to be, fixed. Again, I do not see what is the value of making an infinite useless recursion in one line.

Comment: Works if you ad `; loop()` at the end

Comment: I can re-phrase your lament: "Again, I do not see what is the value of <insert anything you can find on code-golf>".

Answer (score 0):

```
def f():Unit = { println("..."); f() }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: Still doesn't compile.

Comment: I get this error:   illegal start of declaration (possible cause: missing `=' in front of current method body)

Comment: Fixed. Again :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything when I paste it into https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ and press play

Comment: Doesn't matter - I missed the point about the function itself taking an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion for looping is the *standard way* of doing iteration in any functional language, Scala and ECMAScript or by no means special in this regard. And implementing this is a typical beginner's exercise. In Scala, it might look something like this:

```scala
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def whileLoop(condition: => Boolean)(body: => Unit): Unit = 
  if (condition) {
    body
    whileLoop(condition)(body) 
  }

var i = 10
var j = 100

whileLoop { i < j } {
  println(i)
  i += 1
  j -= 1
}
```

Now, you might say "But wait, that's not on one line!" But here's the thing: that's a meaningless requirement because *all code can always be condensed into one line by removing line breaks*:

```scala
@scala.annotation.tailrec def whileLoop(condition: => Boolean)(body: => Unit): Unit = if (condition) { body; whileLoop(condition)(body) }; var i = 10; var j = 100; whileLoop { i < j } { println(i); i += 1; j -= 1 }
```